# gradle-6.9 detects old JAVA path even I have updated JAVA_HOME (react-native)

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, gradlew, java-home

I was using java from this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17` and I have used gradle-6.9 at that time. Later I have installed OpenJDK and now my JAVA_HOME is `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot`. But now if I run gradle using gradle-6.9 version I am getting this

> $ ./gradle
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tr
>   ied location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                                                                 option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

But If I am using any other gradle version for example even 6.9.1 as well everything works fine

eg: 6.9.1, 7.x

I have tried removing cache folder as well but no hope, please help

Answer (score 28):

The previous java got uninstalled but the directory was still present there `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`
Deleted it and it working fine now

Comment: you just save my life. thank you!

Comment: Oh man, I wasted a whole day looking for this same solution!

Comment: Spent an hour searching for this...!! Thank you!